# Select only objects which are covered by the selection box

Tags: figma

Some other design tool I used had this neat feature where selection logic depends on the direction you draw your selection box. E.g, if you start from the top left and drag down + right, anything the box touches is selected (the default behaviour in most packages). But if you start from the bottom right and drag up + left, only things that are completely contained in the marquee get selected (so if your box just touches the edge of an annotation arrow, or a background element, that doesn't get included because it's only partially within the selection).

In Figma I often miss this capability, because I select a screen and some other bits of detritus get captured since they're partially in my selection, and I have to shift click them all away. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

In Figma, hold the `CTRL` key while dragging a marquee over the elements you want to select.

If you are doing this on top level items, and your marque spans the height of elements, the top level items will be selected instead of the elements inside it.

If you are doing this while inside a top level frame, you get to select the items inside the frame.

See the [Selection Marquee](https://forum.figma.com/t/add-pinch-to-zoom-in-and-out-interactions-in-prototypes/35567) topic on Figma Help for more details.